# Painting texture model lag

Tags: texture-painting

I using blender 2.76b or older (2.75, 2.76).
I painting model 1k face, 1024x1024.
my PC corei3, ram 8gb, win 10,  gigabyte  r7 250 2gb.
I use brush radial 1>3 pixel and > 50 pixel no lag.
But brush radial 3 > 50 pixel very lag and slow.
My setting i use default. 
Help me.
Thank so much.

Comment: That makes sense. Some settings make it necessary for more calculations to be made per stroke.

Comment: Stoke space
setting spacing >30% is better than.