# In Texture Paint, Soften Brush and Smear Brush makes Blender Lag

Tags: texture-painting

I have just a plane and an image texture. When using the draw brush, there is no problem, when using soften or smear brush, blender just freezes. Here is the link to the [video:](https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/t21s5y/texture_paint_smooth_brush_and_dissolve_brush/)

How can I fix this?

My rig is 3950x, 2080Ti, 64MB ram so I don't think my PC is the problem.

Comment: So can you help me? Its very painful when it suddenly stops like that.

Comment: Thanks. It's the latest from Steam. v3.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

blender 3.0 does seem terribly slower compared to the same operation in blender 2.93. From [this issue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41404/painting-texture-model-lag) …' I have a suggestion. Try playing around with Brush Settings >> Stroke, and change Spacing from the default of 3% to something higher. (I tried 30%). It isn't what you may want but it is a lot faster. Try adjusting it to where you get good results, but with adequate performance. In the meantime I'll report this is the issues forums 'blender.community/c/rightclickselect' and 'devtalk.blender.org'.

Comment: Ok. thank you very much. This is the clarification that I need because it seems like this issue is just swept under the rag. Again thank you.

Comment: @UnsentimentalJajurie --  I submitted https://devtalk.blender.org/t/in-texture-paint-soften-brush-and-smear-brush-makes-blender-freeze/23176 to the devtalk forum.  Thanks for accepting my answer (I work for reputation points, LOL)

Comment: Oh. No problem.